Confusion about real induction.
I am currently reading General Topology by Pete L. Clark and I find confusion in one of his argument in section 1.1.
First he gave the definition of a set $S$ to be inductive:

Let $a\lt b$ be real number and define subset $S\subset [a,b]$ is inductive if it satisfy:

$a \in S$.
If $a \leq x < b \implies x\in S$, then $[x,y]\subset S$ for some $x < y$.
If $a < x \leq b$ and $[a,x) \subset S$, then $x\in S$.


Then he try to prove theorem called Real Induction:

For $S\subset [a,b]$ the following are equivalent:

$S$ is inductive
$S=[a,b]$


Proof: $(1)\implies (2)$: Let $S\subset [a,b]$ be inductive. Seeking for contradiction, suppose $S'=[a,b]\setminus S$ is non empty. So inf $S'$ exist and is finite.
Case 1: $\color{red}{\text{inf}\,S'=a}$. Then we have $a\in S$ and there exists $y$ such that $a < y$ and $[a,y] \subset S$. Then $y$ is a greater lower bound for $S'$ then $\color{red}{\text{inf}\,S'=a}$: a contradiction.
The rest of the proof I omit since I stuck at the first case and cannot proceed. I do not understand, he assume inf $S'=a$ and later show that this assumption is a contradiction? Thanks for the response!

Is item 3 really what you mean? Surely that says that every $x\in (a,b]$ is in $S$, so that $S=[a,b]$ (since $[a,x)\subset [a,b]$ whenever $a<x\le b$).

Will Pete find and answer this himself? Anyway, he cites this paper, and curiously, the same pseudo(?) contradiction appears there.

@rogerl typo is fixed

@Karl I changed a bit, the original argument is "... so by 2. of the definition of inductive there exist $y\gt x$ such that $[a,y]\subset S$ and thus $y$ is a greater lower bound for $S'...$"

@rogerl Sorry, typo.

@MartinBrandenburg Haha I don't know, I was confused when I see something like that and asking myself what have I missed?

The misunderstanding is based on a very subtle typo in Pete's proof. It should be:

Then $y$ is a greater lower bound for $S'$ than $\inf S' = a$.

Not "then". Or just:

Then $y$ is a lower bound for $S'$ with $y > a$.

And this contradicts $a = \inf S'$.

Actually, I would not consider the first case. We directly prove $\inf S' > a$, there is no need to assume the contrary.

Oh I see, thanks!
